# Install gdb-7.2 on Solaris 11 for segmentation fault error

Tags: c++, gdb, segmentation-fault, solaris, failed-installation

I am trying to install gdb-7.2 on Solaris 11 for debugging a c++ script that is issuing a segmentation fault alert.

Once configured (./configure),

checking whether -fkeep-inline-functions is supported... yes
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile

I move on make (make) however this fails with the following errors:

```
ar: creating libgdb.a ranlib libgdb.a
rm -f gdb
gcc -g -O2 -rdynamic \
 -o gdb gdb.o libgdb.a \
 ../readline/libreadline.a ../opcodes/libopcodes.a ../bfd/libbfd.a \
 ../libiberty/libiberty.a ../libdecnumber/libdecnumber.a \
 -ldl -lcurses -lz -lsocket -lnsl -lm -lsocket -lnsl -ldl -lm \
 -lpython2.6 -lexpat ../libiberty/libiberty.a gnulib/libgnu.a
Undefined first referenced symbol in file
 wattr_on libgdb.a(tui-wingeneral.o)
 wattr_off libgdb.a(tui-wingeneral.o)
ld: fatal: symbol referencing errors. No output written to gdb collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
*** Error code 1 make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `gdb'
```

What could be the possible issue and is there any solution for this?

Comment: That's not enough context to see the real error.

Comment: Do you mean that the error could be located further up in the log? Any idea what I might be after?

Comment: @aaa Yes: the actual error is earlier: some command failed, which caused `make` to fail. You have shown `make` output, but you need to show the *actual* failing command output.

Comment: @EmployedRussian

These are the errors just before that part:

ar: creating libgdb.a
ranlib libgdb.a
rm -f gdb
gcc -g -O2    -rdynamic  \
        -o gdb gdb.o libgdb.a \
           ../readline/libreadline.a ../opcodes/libopcodes.a ../bfd/libbfd.a  ../libiberty/libiberty.a ../libdecnumber/libdecnumber.a     -ldl -lcurses -lz -lsocket -lnsl -lm    -lsocket -lnsl -ldl -lm -lpython2.6  -lexpat  ../libiberty/libiberty.a  gnulib/libgnu.a

Comment: Undefined                       first referenced
 symbol                             in file
wattr_on                            libgdb.a(tui-wingeneral.o)
wattr_off                           libgdb.a(tui-wingeneral.o)
ld: fatal: symbol referencing errors. No output written to gdb
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
*** Error code 1
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `gdb'

Comment: @aaa Don't put this into comments; edit your answer instead. Also see Tom Tromey's answer.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like some bug linking against the Solaris curses library.  Offhand I can't diagnose it.  It's worth digging into and patching upstream...

Meanwhile, you can probably work around it by configuring with --disable-tui.